# Angular how to make pagination in tables

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a simple table of bootstrap. Which is showing result from array. I need to add pagination. Mean it loads the first 40 array then in second pagination it loads 40 like this. I found some example but failed to implement it with bootstrap table. If any one can help in code Thanks.

```
          <table class="table table-responsive-md text-center">
            <thead>
              <tr>
               <th>ID</th>
               <th>NAME</th>
               <th>COMPANY</th>

                 </tr>
                </thead>

              <tbody *ngIf="data">
               <tr *ngFor="let x of data | filterBy: userFilter"  (click)="openDeal(deletecontent, x)">
                 <td>
                   <span class="text-success">{{x.user_id}}</span>
                 </td>


               <td>
                 <div style="text-align: left;">
                  <img [src]="x.userPhoto || 'https://mbtskoudsalg.com/images/user-image-png.png'" class="img-sm" alt="" style="text-align: left;">
                   {{x.name}}                </div>
              </td>

               <td>{{x.cnic}}</td>

                 </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

.ts

```
getClaims(){

  this.emp = true;
  this.url = 'assets/employe.json?';



  this.clientData = this.httpClient.get<any>(this.url,{responseType: 'json'}).
  subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
  this.data4 = data.records;
  this.data = this.data4.filter(item => item.company_id === this.userFilter.company_id);

  this.employesnumber = this.data.count;
  console.log(this.employesnumber);
  });

 }
```

Comment: are ususing client side pagination or server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using ngx-pagination module.

```
 <table class="table table-responsive-md text-center">
        <thead>
          <tr>
           <th>ID</th>
           <th>NAME</th>
           <th>COMPANY</th>

             </tr>
            </thead>

          <tbody *ngIf="data">
           <tr *ngFor="let x of data | filterBy: userFilter | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 40, currentPage: p }""  (click)="openDeal(deletecontent, x)">
             <td>
               <span class="text-success">{{x.user_id}}</span>
             </td>


           <td>
             <div style="text-align: left;">
              <img [src]="x.userPhoto || 'https://mbtskoudsalg.com/images/user-image- 
              png.png'" class="img-sm" alt="" style="text-align: left;">
               {{x.name}}                </div>
          </td>

           <td>{{x.cnic}}</td>

          </tr>
            <pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event"></pagination-controls>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Also declare a variable `p` in your typescript file and dont forget to install the npm package ngx-pagination and importing them in your module